# create a shared project or module with play framework which runs play server and compiles dependancies

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, build-process, typesafe-activator

I am looking to clearly separate my project components into very distinct parts. I have done this many times in other projects using maven but I would like to leverage the play/activator command which runs the play server to build/deploy all projects when a file or dependent file changes. In the end I would end up with multiple deployable units depending on a single "core" project or module.

In most cases the core module consists of business logic and domain model objects which becomes a library for other projects to leverage. Below is an example layout .

```
my-app-web-site(play)---\              /--Partner-api
                         \            /
                          CORE project
                          /           \  
my-app-admin-site(play)--/             \--Android mobile
```

In the ideal world I would run

```
./activator ~run
```

And the web app I am working on would start and any changes I made to my core lib / module would be compiled and deployed like any other object in a traditional play web app.

The question is .. is this possible with just the play or activator command or do I need a separate sbt setup?

-- EDIT

So I figured it out! To make this work I put my current two projects called "newburyCore" and "newburyWeb" together into a sub folder and copied activator and the activator-version.jar into the the new root dir. Next I created a project dir with a simple Build.scala that makes the web project depend on the core project. It is very minimal at this point here is the code:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object BuildSettings {
  val buildOrganization = "cti"
  val buildVersion      = "1.0.0"
  val buildScalaVersion = "2.10.0"

  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq (
    organization := buildOrganization,
    version      := buildVersion,
    scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion
  )
}

object RootBuild extends Build {
  import BuildSettings._
  lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file("."), settings = buildSettings)
    .aggregate(newburyCore, newburyWeb)

  lazy val newburyCore = Project(id = "newburyCore", base = file("newburyCore"), settings = buildSettings)

  lazy val newburyWeb = Project(id = "newburyWeb", base = file("newburyWeb"), settings = buildSettings)
    .dependsOn(newburyCore)
}
```

The project layout looks like this

```
/newbury
        activator
        activator.jar
        /project
                /Build.scala
        /newburyCore
        /newburyWeb
```

Now in the newbury folder I can start the activator change the project to newburyWeb and execute ~run. This works exactly how I want it. The play server runs and all the dependencies from core are compiled as I make changes and are reflected in the newburyWeb project and corresponding web pages.

```
./activator

>project newburyWeb

[newburyWeb] ~run
```

So thats how I did it. I could not find any docs about doing this and in searching the web I found bits and pieces from the sbt docs and play docs. The magic here is the running of the play server which was central to my problem. Hope this helps someone looking to do a multi project play app.

Comment: So...what's your question then? I can only imagine what one might be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Gilt activator template (https://github.com/gilt/activator-gilt-app)? It sounds very similar to what you did.

Also, you might want to make your EDIT an answer to your own question.